# How to deal with licensing when importing remote packages in golang?

Tags: licensing, golang

In golang, one can import packages with urls such as `import "github.com/foo/bar"`. Do I still have to include the license of the remote package, as I'm not including library source code directly? How should I deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not including the source code directly, you are not redistributing the code. However, you are using the library. So, you should follow what the library's licence says about usage.